# Adding a link to the bottom banner of SharePoint site

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'm wondering how can I add a link to the footer of SharePoint site? I would like to show that link in all sites.

Comment: Create a footer section as per your need in master page. And apply this master page as a default/custom... It will reflect in all the pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create SharePoint Framework (SPFx) component of type Extension --> Application Customizer to create footer.

Step by step instructions on how to create SPFx footer component can be found can be found [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/guidance/migrate-from-usercustomactions-to-spfx-extensions#create-a-new-sharepoint-framework-solution).